# Angular ng-repeat inside ng-repeat collapse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been attempting to perform an ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat collapse. My inner ng-repeat, repeats the entire array inside of every div. I have tried to track by index but still no resolve:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="markets">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="m in marketResults | limitTo:5">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="m.isCollapsed = !m.isCollapsed">{{m.marketname}}
        </div>
        <div uib-collapse="!m.isCollapsed">
            <div ng-repeat="s in stuff" >
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Address}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.GoogleLink}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Products}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Schedule}}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside Controller:

```
_getLocation: function(key) { //extract latlng from _recordsCache

    var latLong = this._recordsCache[key];

    // console.log(latLong);
    fmCoordinates.lat = latLong.lat;
    fmCoordinates.lng = latLong.lng;

    var promise = requestMarkets(fmCoordinates.lat,fmCoordinates.lng);
    promise.then(function(marketData) {
      $scope.marketResults = marketData.results; //receiving market data
      $scope.quantity = 5; //limit market data to 5
      $scope.marketInfo = [];
      $scope.getInfo = function(){
        return $scope.marketInfo;
      }

      for(var property in $scope.marketResults) {
        var id = $scope.marketResults[property].id;
        console.log(id);
        $scope.marketInfo.push(getDetails(id));// brings back the details
      };
      console.log($scope.getInfo());


    }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
    if( this._recordsCache.hasOwnProperty(key) )
      return latLong;//then after use .loc attribute
    else
      return false;
  },
```

Comment: I don't see where you use `m` to filter `stuff` data so I would assume in every `m` it will show the entire array. You could do something like `ng-repeat="s in m.stuff`. But you need to provide more detail to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: yes...inner repeats are generally(but not always) repeating over an array of items in the parent object isolated in the outer repeat. Show data smple

Comment: I have two arrays. The first array bring me back the names of the markets [{marketname, id}]. Then I return a second array using the id from the first array which returns an array with market details. [{Schedule, Address, Hours}]. The two array are in sequence. First I am displaying the marketname on the div panel, then when you click the panel you see the details from the second array

Comment: In that case, does your getInfo() function, accept market id as a parameter like getInfo(m.id) ?

Comment: @user4955287 can you show how you get the second array then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the second array as a property of each item in first array. See below code:

**HTML:**
Instead of writing ng-repeat = "s in stuff", we will write ng-repeat = "s in m.stuff"

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="markets">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="m in marketResults | limitTo:5">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="m.isCollapsed = !m.isCollapsed">{{m.marketname}}
        </div>
        <div uib-collapse="!m.isCollapsed">
            <div ng-repeat="s in m.stuff" >
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Address}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.GoogleLink}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Products}}</p>
                <p>{{s.$$state.value.Schedule}}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**
First load marketResults array. Then in for loop, loop through each element in marketResults and load the second array using id and save it as stuff property for each element, so we can access second array using m.stuff in ng-repeat

```
_getLocation: function(key) { //extract latlng from _recordsCache

var latLong = this._recordsCache[key];

// console.log(latLong);
fmCoordinates.lat = latLong.lat;
fmCoordinates.lng = latLong.lng;

var promise = requestMarkets(fmCoordinates.lat,fmCoordinates.lng);
promise.then(function(marketData) {
  $scope.marketResults = marketData.results; //receiving market data
  $scope.quantity = 5; //limit market data to 5

  for(var market in $scope.marketResults) {

    market.stuff = getDetails(market.id);// brings back the details

  };

}, function(reason) {
  console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
});
if( this._recordsCache.hasOwnProperty(key) )
  return latLong;//then after use .loc attribute
else
  return false;
},
```

Comment: This is not working. I am receiving undefined for my id value

Comment: Verify your marketResults array to check how you get the id value

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init to keep children on each parent row. Pass id to a getChild(m.id) and get child and then use it on second loop.

ng-init="rowchild = getChild(m.id)"

```
<div id="markets">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="m in marketResults | limitTo:5" ng-init="rowchild = getChild(m.id)">

        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="m.isCollapsed = !m.isCollapsed">
            {{m.marketname}}
        </div>

        <div uib-collapse="m.isCollapsed">

            <div ng-repeat="s in rowchild">

                <p>{{s.Address}}</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="markets">
        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="m in marketResults | limitTo:5">
            <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="m.isCollapsed = !m.isCollapsed">{{m.marketname}}
            </div>
            <div uib-collapse="!m.isCollapsed">
                <div>
                    <p>{{m.stuff.$$state.value.Address}}</p>
                    <p>{{m.stuff.$$state.value.GoogleLink}}</p>
                    <p>{{m.stuff.$$state.value.Products}}</p>
                    <p>{{m.stuff.$$state.value.Schedule}}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Inside Controller

```
  _getLocation: function(key) { //extract latlng from _recordsCache

    var latLong = this._recordsCache[key];

    // console.log(latLong);
    fmCoordinates.lat = latLong.lat;
    fmCoordinates.lng = latLong.lng;


    var promise = requestMarkets(fmCoordinates.lat,fmCoordinates.lng);
    promise.then(function(marketData) {
      $scope.marketResults = marketData.results; //receiving market data
      $scope.quantity = 5; //limit market data to 5
      $scope.marketInfo = [];
      console.log($scope.marketResults);

      for (var i = 0; i < marketData.results.length; i++){
        marketData.results[i].stuff = getDetails(marketData.results[i].id);
      };

    }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
    });
    if( this._recordsCache.hasOwnProperty(key) )
      return latLong;//then after use .loc attribute
    else
      return false;
  },
```